# Linear Projections: Bounded/Continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis

Are linear (nonorthogonal) projections on (pre) Hilbert spaces necessarily bounded/continuous?
*(can you give a proof or counterexample)*

Comment: Not in general http://mathoverflow.net/questions/94316/projections-which-are-not-completely-bounded

Comment: It does not give answer on my question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Projection:
$$P:\mathcal{l}^2\to\mathcal{l}^2:P(b_1)=b_1,P(b_2)=b_2,\ldots,P(b)=0\text{ with }b_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}e_k$$
Discontinuity:
$$x_n\to(\frac{1}{1},\frac{1}{2},\ldots),P(x_n)\nrightarrow P(\frac{1}{1},\frac{1}{2},\ldots)\text{ with }x_n:=b_n$$
Remark:

*This can be established even nicer when noticing that any continuous operator must have closed kernel...*

Comment: You mean $P(b_n)=b_n$, $P(b)=0$ for all $b$ that are not in the linear hull of the $b_n$? This linear hull is not equal to $l^2$ but it is dense in $l^2$ since it contains all finite sequences. Then $N(I-P)$ is not closed. Nice example!

Comment: Thx ;) no I first complete to a Hamel basis then define it on that and then linearly expand it

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to construct unbounded projections in non-complete inner product spaces. Take $C([0,1])$ equipped with the $L^2$-scalar product. Then 
$$
(P(x))(t) := x(t) - x(0)
$$
is an unbounded projection. No idea about the Hilbert space case.